# How can I make my function access variables in this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, nse

Taking into consideration the following database (called data), I want to make a function that retrieves the first "Start" position of a given "Letter". I want my function to take the dataframe and Letter as inputs. And I'd like to do this without the use of libraries.

| Letter | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| B | 4 | 5 |
| B | 6 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 6 |
| C | 4 | 8 |
| C | 9 | 3 |
| C | 7 | 3 |

I thought the first step should be to subset the specific "Letter" I want to get the "Start" position for:

`newdata <- subset(data, data == "A")`

This resulted in a dataframe that's specific for the Letter A:

| Letter | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 4 |

Step two should be to index the subsetted dataframe for the first start position:

`newdata[1,2]`
Output: 1

It worked therefore I made a function based on the aforementioned steps where x is a named dataframe and y is the variable to be selected for:

`getFirstLetter <-  function(x, y){ newdata <- subset(x, x == "y") return(newdata[1,2]) }`

Tested the function but got NA:
`getFirstLetter(data, A)`
Output: NA

Troubleshooting code:
`getFirstLetter(data, "A")`
Output: NA

I'd appreciate some guidance on why my function isn't returning the intended output.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.character(substitute())`:

```
getFirstLetter <- function(x, y) { 
  y <- as.character(substitute(y))
  newdata <- subset(x, Letter == y)
  newdata[1,2]
}

getFirstLetter(data, A)
# 1
```

A slightly more succinct approach would be to index into `x` using `match()`:

```
getFirstLetter <- function(x, y) { 
  y <- as.character(substitute(y))
  x[[match(y, x$Letter), "Start"]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Letter, ~Start, ~End,
      "A",     1L,   2L,
      "A",     3L,   3L,
      "A",     2L,   4L,
      "B",     4L,   5L,
      "B",     6L,   1L,
      "B",     2L,   6L,
      "C",     4L,   8L,
      "C",     9L,   3L,
      "C",     7L,   3L
  )
getFirstLetter <-  function(df, letter){
  newdata <- subset(df, Letter == letter)[1,2] 
  return(newdata) 
}

getFirstLetter(df = df, letter = "A")
```